# Can summation of gradient descent runs on subsets approximate gradient descent run on set?

Tags: machine-learning, gradient-descent

I have a training set M, which I then split into two subsets, say, M1 & M2.

If I run gradient descent on each subset to come up with a linear regression which approximates the data in M1 & M2, if take the weighted sum of the linear equations, would that sum be an adequate approximation of M?

I.e.

Run gradient descent on M1 to get linear equation f(x)
Run gradient descent on M2 to get linear equation g(x)

then does the following hold true:
(size(M1)/size(M))*f(x) + (size(M2)/size(M))*g(x) ~ result of gradient descent on M

Comment: What objective function are you taking about?  Gradient descent is a way of doing optimization. Suppose M1 and M2 happen to be points in two tight clusters. If your objective function is one that tends to converge to the center of the larger cluster, the answer is clearly no. If it's one that converges to something like the average, maybe yes...